# How could I change the hex number for decimal number in re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `"call 0x558f to add 0xaaef"`，and I want to change the hex numbers in that string to decimal numbers, then print out the result with those numbers re-inserted, like `"call xxxx to add xxxx"`.

I tried to code this like this:

```
# coding=utf-8 
import re
__author__ = 'sudo'

def hextodecimal(match):
    print "Return the  decimal number for hex string"
    print match.group()
    vaule = int(hex(match.group()),16)
    return vaule   

p = re.compile(r"\b0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+\b ")

print p.sub(hextodecimal, "call 0x568a to add 0x333f")
```

although I managed to extract the `"0x568a"` portion, there is an error:

```
Return the  decimal number for hex string
0x568a 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/pythonProject/Guessnumber/hextooct.py", line 15, in <module>
    print p.sub(hextodecimal, "call 0x568a to add 0x333f")
  File "F:/pythonProject/Guessnumber/hextooct.py", line 11, in hextodecimal
    vaule = int(hex(match.group()),16)
TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `hex()` call; that function used to *produce* hex output, not to parse it.

Group the hexadecimal digits portion of the matched text, then pass only that portion to `int(..., 16)`, then convert that parsed integer to a string:

```
def hextodecimal(match):
    return str(int(match.group(1), 16)) 

p = re.compile(r"\b0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]+)\b")
print p.sub(hextodecimal, "call 0x568a to add 0x333f")
```

I removed the trailing space from your pattern too.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> def hextodecimal(match):
...     return str(int(match.group(1), 16))
...
>>> p = re.compile(r"\b0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]+)\b")
>>> p.sub(hextodecimal, "call 0x568a to add 0x333f")
'call 22154 to add 13119'
```

Comment: thank you,  the first time i make a wrong return from the function hextodecimal,  it should be return as str ,  thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

With the 0x prefix, Python can distinguish hex and decimal automatically.

> > > print int("0xdeadbeef", 0)

3735928559

> > > print int("10", 0)

10

Comment: Very interesting, true, but that doesn't fix the issue the OP had. This is, at best, a comment.